# Displaying a sequence of SVG Images

Tags: java, svg

I am trying to make an animation by displaying a series of SVG images uisng Java language. Here is a part of my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < svgDocList.size(); i++)
{                    
    try {                       
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
svgCanvas.setDocument(svgDocList.get(i));
}
```

When I run this, the canvas displayed only the first image of the list but did not get update with other images of the list. What could be wrong? or Any other ways of displaying a series of svg images?

Answer (score 0):

I work with Javascript in SVG. So I'd consider the following...
I assume SVGDocList is an array of SVG images that are already well situated and formed, ready for all requests.

When I loaded the first image, before I loaded the next, I must remove the previous.
Also it seems that image onload should participate in the process in calling the next image.

Just a few thoughts that may help.

Comment: Thanks I will consider about that.